# Rspec: testing cancan ability with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, cancan

I am using cancan gem.

I have ability defined in my class:

```
module Gexcore
   class Myability
       include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
       can :delete_user, User do |victim|
      ..
        end
    end

  end
end
```

I am testing the ability to delete user with RSpec:

```
RSpec.describe "Permissions to delete user", :type => :request do
  describe 'del user' do
    it 'superadmin can delete user' do
      superadmin = double(User, :id => 10, <<some other fields>>)

      ability = Mymodule::Myability.new(superadmin)

      victim = double(User)

      res = superadmin_ability.can?(:user_del, victim)

      expect(res).to eq true

    end
  end

end
```

My user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :can?, :cannot?, :to => :ability
  ...
end
```

But it doesn't see method `can? :delete_user, User` from my ability.
It expects User class but RSpec calls it with RSpec::Mocks::Double class.

How to test correctly ability from cancan gem using Rspec mocks ?

Answer (score 0):

RSpec is using a Double class because that's where it ends in your code. The class must be `User` for RSpec to apply the rules.

```
let(:user) do 
  u = User.new
  u.stub!(:some_qualifier_in_your_delete_user_declaration? => true)
  u
end
```

[See this SO archive for more of a reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306777/how-do-i-properly-test-cancan-abilities-with-rspec)